# Get user installed apps and each app ratings

Tags: facebook

I have created a new facebook application.I am trying using Graph api 2.2, once user installs my app to get his already installed apps and each installed app ratings.

While reading documentation i see such action in not possible. I was wondering if there is another way (not using Graph api) to get applications. Also i cannot understand why facebook is not allowing (once your app is granted) to read installed apps but is allowing to read inbox,friends,personal which is supposed to be confidential data!

Thank you
Stefanos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get the installed Apps of a user, with or without the Graph API. Everything that may be possible somehow without the the Graph API would not be allowed, because that would be scraping: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

You need to think as a user, not as a developer. I would not want any App to know which other Apps i am using. There is no serious way how an App would deal with that information anyway.

Also, the permission to get access to the inbox will not get approved in most cases, and you can only get the friends who authorized the same App too.